# Authenticating username and password against LDAP using ADODB.Connection

Tags: ldap

I have the following code:

```
object recs;
ADODB.Connection conn = new ADODB.Connection();
ADODB.Recordset rs = new ADODB.Recordset();

conn.Provider = "ADSDSOObject";

string SQLStmt = "SELECT cn FROM 'LDAP://" + server + "/o=nwu/ou=users' WHERE cn='" + userName + "'";
conn.Open("ADs Provider", "****", "****");

rs = conn.Execute(SQLStmt,out recs, 0);
```

This reads the information for the username.

How do I actually check if the password matches this user?

Answer (score 0):

Your application must authenticate the connection, that is, set the authorization state of the connection using the LDAP bind request.

Comment: Could you perhaps point me in the right direction? An article or something demonstrating this?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer to your question and many more details in the MSDN website.

Read this: [Building Secure ASP.NET Applications: Authentication, Authorization, and Secure Communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649227.aspx)